# IF Inside A Function For Content Filter

Tags: the-content

Trying to use a filter for post content. But how do i make an IF work inside the function.

```
<?php function my_the_content_filter($content) {
  } add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' ); ?>
```

So i need to add this inside of it.

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "heading_image", true)) : ?>  
      <img src="<?php $image_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, "heading_image", true);
     $post_image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, $size='full' );
           echo $post_image_data[0]; ?>" style="max-width:1000px;" />
     <?php endif; ?>
```

I cant seem to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This should be it -

```
<?php function my_the_content_filter( $content )
{
    if( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "heading_image", true) )
    {
        $image_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "heading_image", true);
        $post_image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' ); ?>

        // checks if you have got the source
        if( isset($post_image_data[0]) )
        {
            // if image is show before the content
            $content = '<img src="'. $post_image_data[0] .'" style="max-width:1000px;" />' . $content;
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' ); ?>
```